# what do you call a book containing questions?

Tags: single-word-requests

what do you call a book that only contains questions and answers, no other stuff. Maybe "questionnaire" is one but I think questionnaires only contain questions.

Comment: a study guide..

Comment: a book of quizzical nature

Comment: A question book with answers.

Comment: A *Question Bank* usually includes the respective *correct answers* as well, not just questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible terms include:

- [quiz book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mastermind-Quiz-Book-Boswell-Taylor/dp/0671067958/ref=cm_lmf_tit_1/278-5901430-4846552) - Implies that it's a book containing quizzes or tests.
- [workbook](http://www.schoolzone.com/best-kids/workbooks) - Often accompanies a student textbook, and contains supplementary questions/problems to answer/solve.
- [puzzle book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001O9BY74) - Contains a bunch of puzzle problems/questions for entertainment.

A [study guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Study_guide) or [prep guide](http://gre-preparation-guide.blogspot.com/) also often contains questions and answers, but not exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it a **catechism**, in the same non-religious way they speak of "Java Developer's Bible".

The other option could be a **handbook** (the option brought by O'Henry's *The Handbook Of Hymen*).

Answer (score 0):

Informally, a "Q & A". Otherwise, I'd be inclined towards "catechism" as well, except for the religious connotations: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catechism